# Not downloading correctly files from APEX

Tags: sql, plsql, download, oracle-apex

I have a little problem. I'm trying to download files from APEX application. The file downloads correctly but the browser doesn't recognize the file as a PDF. The code below works perfectly but lacks the recognition of the filetype.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DOWNLOAD_LIST
   (p_id_list in VARCHAR2) AS
   v_mime  VARCHAR2(2000);
   v_length  NUMBER;
   v_file_name VARCHAR2(2000);
   Lob_loc  BLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT MIME_TYPE, BLOB_CONTENT, CODI ,DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_content)   
   INTO v_mime,lob_loc,v_file_name,v_length
   FROM table
   WHERE ID_LIST = p_id_list;

   -- set up HTTP header
   -- use an NVL around the mime type and 
   -- if it is a null set it to application/octect
   -- application/octect may launch a download window from windows

   -- I've tried to put either pdf or octet. The database file has 'application/pdf' as mime_type
   owa_util.mime_header( nvl(v_mime,'application/pdf'), FALSE );      
   -- set the size so the browser knows how much to download
   htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_length);
   -- the filename will be used by the browser if the users does a save as
   --htp.p('Content-Disposition:  attatchment; filename="'||replace(replace(substr(v_file_name,instr(v_file_name,'/')+1),chr(10),null),chr(13),null)|| '"');
   htp.p('Content-Disposition: attatchment; filename="'||v_file_name||'.pdf'||'"');
   -- close the headers            
   owa_util.http_header_close;
   -- download the BLOB
   wpg_docload.download_file( Lob_loc );
end DOWNLOAD_LIST;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple; requires you to take some additional steps, as described in [Creating PDF Reports with Oracle Application Express 5.0 and Oracle REST Data Services](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/PDF%20Printing/Creating%20PDF%20Reports%20with%20Oracle%20Application%20Express%205.0%20and%20Oracle%20REST%20Data%20Services.html). Have a look, that tutorial takes 20 minutes to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't want to create a report and print it. I have a Blob file in DB and I want to download it as a PDF (same as origin).

Comment: Aha; sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. Why would you do it that way (using a stored procedure)? Create an Apex page and download it from there. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a slight issue with your content-length:

This is code I have in production and it does show a .pdf file properly using the browser built-in viewer:

```
PROCEDURE   PR_SHOW_REPORT(io_blReport            IN OUT BLOB,
                       i_vcContentDisposition IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'inline',
                       i_vcFilename           IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'reportresult.pdf') IS
 l_mime        VARCHAR2 (255);
 l_length      NUMBER;
 l_file_name   VARCHAR2 (2000);
 lob_loc       BLOB;
BEGIN
 OWA_UTIL.mime_header ('application/pdf', FALSE);
 HTP.p ('Content-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(io_blReport));
 HTP.p ('Content-Disposition: ' || i_vcContentDisposition ||'; filename="' || i_vcFilename || '"');
 OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;
 WPG_DOCLOAD.download_file(io_blReport);
END;
```